# Can a shadow animatronic hurt you?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-3

I’ve been playing FNAF 3 and I keep being jump scared by the shadow animatronic but it never kills me. Can it actually hurt you or is it just there to scare you?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it can't hurt you, but in FNAF2 Shadow Bonnie can crash your game if you stare at it for too long. There's only a rare chance you would have Shadow Bonnie appear in the game. I once had that experience with Shadow Bonnie and staring at it crashed my game, so I'd avoid him.

Shadow Freddy can't hurt you either, and will normally be sitting down on the floor, not in your office, but I think in the Repair/Maintenance room.

Shadow Dee-Dee is like Dee-Dee, with the same characteristics. She only appears in Ultra Custom night, not in any game except for Ultra Custom Night.

Answer (score 0):

Shadow animatronics are two minor ghost-like hallucinations that haunt Freddy Fazbear's Pizza. They are dark, mysterious versions of Freddy and Bonnie sporting with white eyes and teeth. Encountering one of them is very rare. Similar to Golden Freddy from the first game, if the player looks at one each of them for too long will cause the game to crash or freeze in the mobile port. **They never attack or jumpscare the player** however since they have nothing to do with the player except for crashing (or freezing in mobile version) the game after observing them for too long.

Comment: If you're going to copy something from another site, providing attribution is not optional.

Comment: @Frank What makes you say the answer is copied?